# Error extending class in Dart: "no_generative_constructors_in_superclass"

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, constructor, path

I'm encountering an issue in Dart related to class inheritance and constructors. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
error: The class 'PathWithActionHistory' can't extend 'Path' because 'Path' only has factory constructors (no generative constructors), and 'PathWithActionHistory' has at least one generative constructor. (no_generative_constructors_in_superclass at [paintroid] lib\core\path_with_action_history.dart:3)
```

**Code Snippets:**

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

class PathWithActionHistory extends Path {
  final actions = <PathAction>[];

  @override
  void moveTo(double x, double y) {
    actions.add(MoveToAction(x, y));
    super.moveTo(x, y);
  }

  @override
  void lineTo(double x, double y) {
    actions.add(LineToAction(x, y));
    super.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  @override
  void close() {
    actions.add(const CloseAction());
    super.close();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to extend the `Path` class with a new class called `PathWithActionHistory`. However, I'm getting an error indicating that `Path` only has factory constructors and `PathWithActionHistory` has at least one generative constructor. How can I resolve this issue?

**Additional Context:**
Along with the provided problem, I am also getting other errors; however, the mentioned error is the primary error that has to be fixed.

1. error: Missing concrete implementations of 'Path.addArc', 'Path.addOval', 'Path.addPath', 'Path.addPolygon', and 22 more.
2. error: The method 'moveTo' is always abstract in the supertype.
3. error: The method 'lineTo' is always abstract in the supertype.
4. error: The method 'close' is always abstract in the supertype.

**Flutter Doctor:(Updated)**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2792], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category
```

Comment: Did you read https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#no_generative_constructors_in_superclass and if so, what do you need clarification on?

Comment: How to remove those errors?

Answer (score 1):

`Path` does not provide a public, non-`factory` constructor, so **it cannot be derived from with `extends`**. (Before Dart 3 introduced [the `interface` modifier for classes](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface), giving a class private constructors with only public `factory` constructors was the typical way to prevent subtyping with `extends`.)

You alternatively can use `implements` to create your own `Path` class that wraps an existing `Path` object and forwards to it:

```dart
class PathWithActionHistory implements Path {
  final actions = <PathAction>[];

  final Path _path;

  PathWithActionHistory.from(this._path);

  @override
  void moveTo(double x, double y) {
    actions.add(MoveToAction(x, y));
    _path.moveTo(x, y);
  }

  @override
  void lineTo(double x, double y) {
    actions.add(LineToAction(x, y));
    _path.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  @override
  void close() {
    actions.add(const CloseAction());
    _path.close();
  }

  @override
  PathFillType get fillType => _path.fillType;

  @override
  void set fillType(PathFillType value) => _path.fillType = value;

  // ... etc. ...
}
```

Note that by using `implements`, you must provide implementations for *all* methods (including property getters and setters) of the `Path` interface.  Although it's more work, it also safer since if new methods are added to `Path`, your code will fail to compile instead of silently misbehaving at runtime.